# I have introduce new API and want to build android jellybean SDK, what is the command to build

Tags: android

I have added one API  for camera use case, I would like to build SDK for the same. Please let me know the build command. 
I have tried couple of them as below , and none of them have worked :(

- `make sdk`
- `make -j16 sdk`
- `make -j8 PRODUCT-sdk-sdk showcommands dist`

I am building on ubuntu.

Comment: You should always say more than 'doesn't work'

Comment: Probably pointing out error may help to solve the reason. Anyway try out following                                                              "make update-api " and
"make sdk"